# Some strange behavior Python list and dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Can anyone explain why this happened with list and how to clean list after appending to another list?

```
>>> t = {}
>>> t["m"] = []
>>> t
{'m': []}
>>> t["m"].append('qweasdasd aweter')
>>> t["m"].append('asdasdaf ghghdhj')
>>> t
{'m': ['qweasdasd aweter', 'asdasdaf ghghdhj']}
>>> r = []
>>> r.append(t)
>>> r
[{'m': ['qweasdasd aweter', 'asdasdaf ghghdhj']}]
>>> t["m"] = []
>>> r
[{'m': []}]
```

Comment: You are calling this behaviour *strange*, assuming that python will implicitly copy the whole dictionary when you `append` to r, In almost every case Python doesn't do anything unless you've explicitly told it to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a normal behaviour. Python uses references to store elements.
When you do `r.append(t)` python will store `t` in `r`. If you modify `t` later, `t` in `r` will be also modified because it's the same object.

If you want to make `t` independant from the value stored in `r` you have to copy it. Look at the [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `r.append(t)` you are saying "Store a reference to the value stored in `t` at the end of the list `r`". The dictionary `t` references is not copied, so when you modify `t` you modify the data referenced by `r`.

This behaviour can be seen more clearly here:

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = x
>>> x.append(1)
>>> y
[1]
```

This sets `y` to the value referenced by `x` so when `x` changes it appears that `y` changes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are mutable in Python, take a copy instead

```
>>> import copy
>>> r.append(copy.copy(t))
>>> t
{'m': ['qweasdasd aweter', 'asdasdaf ghghdhj']}
>>> r
[{'m': ['qweasdasd aweter', 'asdasdaf ghghdhj']}]
>>> t["m"]=None
>>> r
[{'m': ['qweasdasd aweter', 'asdasdaf ghghdhj']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do:

```
import copy
r.append(copy.deepcopy(t))
```

and that should work.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. When you assign a object to a variable, python won't copy that object to your variable. It will simply assign the reference of original object to your new object.

```
In [1]: a = [1,2]   
In [2]: b = a
In [3]: a.remove(1)
In [4]: b
Out[4]: [2]
```

Here b will only hold the reference of original list a. If you want to override this behavior, you can use the copy module.

```
In [7]: import copy
In [8]: a = [1,2]
In [9]: b = copy.deepcopy(a)
In [10]: a.remove(1)
In [11]: b
Out[11]: [1, 2]
```

deepcopy duplicates everything including individual elements.